# Django South add_inrospection_rules for django-private-files field with callable as value for field attribute

Tags: django, django-south

My project uses South and I want to use [django-private-files](https://bitbucket.org/vvangelovski/django-private-files/src) fields for some of my apps. private_files does not provide introspection rules, so I wrote some in my app's fields.py file. Usually theses are pretty straight forward, but I never had to write rules for a custom field that has an attribute who's value is a callable with arguments. This is what I got:

```
# myapp/models.py
from django.db import models
import fields # to add south introspection rules
from private_files import PrivateFileField

class Image(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField("description", max_length = 200)
    image = PrivateFileField("image file", upload_to = 'uploads')
```

-

```
# myapp/fields.py
from private_files import PrivateFileField
"""
South introspection rules
"""

from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
rules = [
    (
        (PrivateFileField,),
        [],
        {
            "condition": ["condition", {}],
            "attachment" : ["attachment", {"default": True}],
        },
    )]

add_introspection_rules(
    rules,
    ["^private_files\.models\.fields\.PrivateFileField"])
```

These rules are for the [PrivateFileField](https://bitbucket.org/vvangelovski/django-private-files/src/f2cfbbb3b878/private_files/models/fields.py#cl-36)

When I run `./manage.py schemamigration --initial myapp` I get `TypeError: is_user_authenticated() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Andrew Godwin: "South's introspection system isn't designed for a second level of call-ability."([reference](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/south-users/XO5kk5iClOQ/discussion)) This means that the only way around this problem at this time is to omit the rule for the `condition` argument and just tell **south** that the field is OK. So:

```
# myapp/fields.py
from private_files import PrivateFileField
"""
South introspection rules
"""

from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
rules = [
    (
        (PrivateFileField,),
        [],
        {
            "attachment" : ["attachment", {"default": True}],
        },
    )]

add_introspection_rules(
    rules,
    ["^private_files\.models\.fields\.PrivateFileField"])
```